# Cannot use JSP tag or Servlet when HTML is generated from XML

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My web pages are rendered from XML.
It is dynamic without to create HTML pages or JSP.
The source code is described as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{templateid}", produces = "text/html; charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String get(@PathVariable final String templateid) {
    //render from xml to html as string
    return string;
}
```

But, I can not use JSP tags or Servlet since it is not a JSP pages (the string returned above is html).

I want to use JSP tags when these pages are generated

Do you have any way to solve my problem I'm having?

Thanks,

Comment: JSP tags are used to generate HTML, on the server, inside JSPs. You already have HTML, and you're not using JSPs. So JSP tags are irrelevant. And you're already using Spring MVC, so why would you use an additional servlet rather than a Spring MVC controller? What do you *actually* want to achieve?

Comment: How can I use jsp tags when pages are generated from XML (It is dynamic)?

Comment: If it's a JSP page, that's okay.
But my pages are generated from XML

Comment: Again, that doesn't make any sense. JSP tags, as their name implies, are supposed to be used inside JSPs, and you're not using JSPs. Your question is similar to : how can I use piano strings when playing my guitar. Piano strings are used in pianos, not in guitars.

Comment: How can I generate jsp from xml and use it as jsp pages.

Comment: You can't. That's not how JSPs work. Again, explain what you're *actually* trying to achieve. Not the solution you've imagined to achieve that.

Comment: I have not found the best solution. Currently I am using a class Parser to render the response. Many thanks,

Comment: Xml files (defined components).I have to create web pages from those xml files and I can CRUD Operations (using Spring boot)

Comment: If you have any solutions please tell me.

Comment: Well, parse your XML into Java objects, and use whatever view engine you want (JSPs, Thymeleaf, whatever) to display those Java objects.